# How to measure current with a multimeter? Currently getting inconsistent measurements

Tags: current, multimeter

I have a current controlled power supply giving out 8 A (at least that's what I'm setting), plugged into a cable (call it #1) which is then connected via screws&crimps to a copper coil (call it #2, 70 turns, 1.25 mm diameter, 25.4 m length) to generate a magnetic field.

At the crimps, with a multimeter with a 10 A max fuse, I measure 3.8 A. I am using croc clips on the screws.

If I connect the ground of the multimeter to the '-' terminal of the power supply, the reading becomes 5.5 A.

**Why**?

Is it normal that the multimeter does not read exactly the correct current? Should I trust that current or the one displayed on the power supply?

P.S. = cable #1 is probably not rated for 8 A. But that should not affect the current right?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyDC5J.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

***Image of test setup:***

[image: annotated image with power supply, cable, crimp+screw connection, multimeter, and copper coil]

Comment: Can you provide a sketch or schematic of how you are connecting your multimeter to the circuit and what that circuit is?

Comment: Sure, I added a diagram.

Comment: No, you added a photograph.  We need a wiring diagram (schematic) to see how exactly you have connected your ammeter.  To correctly measure current, the ammeter must be connected so that ALL the current you want to measure passes through the meter.  It appears from the photo that you have connected the meter between two points in the circuit, rather than breaking the circuit to insert the meter (but it is hard to tell from the photo). There is a schematic drawing tool available when editing your question - just hit "Control-M" to open it.

Comment: Yes, I see it. I have the ammeter in parallel. Wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplest answer: you are using the multimeter **incorrectly** and can cause damage to your equipment that way. From the looks of your photo, your multimeter is **shorting out** the the coil in the present configuration. You should connect the multimeter like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQ6L7n.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The small cable will not change the current recorded by the power supply, but will add resistance to your system. This may be what is **currently saving** your multimeter's 10A fuse.

*PLEASE* do some more research on how to use your instruments. This will help avoid damaging them or, worse, hurting yourself/others.

For using the multimeter, remember these things:

- An *ideal* voltmeter has *infinite* resistance and is connected *in parallel* to the voltage being measured
- An *ideal* ammeter has *zero* resistance and is connected *in series* with the current being measured

Comment: Thanks. But with 8 A set by the power supply, I can only have at most 8 A through the ammeter right? So how could I blow the 10 A fuse?

Comment: @SuperCiocia first, please, disconnect the multimeter.

Comment: Everything's been off for an hour. Nothing is connected anymore.

Comment: What's the risk?

Comment: Further, most hand multimeters are only rated at 10A for short cycles: 10 or 30 seconds on, 10 minutes disconnected. Next, the current limit of the power supply is not perfect. It is possible to get more than 10A from a power supply for a short period of time because it has internal output capacitance. The current/voltage limits aren't perfect and can damage devices.

Comment: But isn't the worst case scenario just blowing the fuse, saving he multimeter?

Comment: With small input wires and a load that's probably close to a dead short (thicker copper wire), you probably don't have to worry about that current spike, but if you disconnected your coil while leaving the multimeter connected as per your post's diagram, you could damage the multimeter. *Please use this (shared?) equipment carefully and correctly.*

Comment: At a current limit of 8A, leaving the multimeter connected could overheat other circuitry without blowing the fuse. Read the ratings from the multimeter manual on using the 10A current measurement setting.

Comment: Thanks. No I never disconnected the coils. But realise the ammeter should go in series, not in parallel, I didn't give it too much thought. I'm still learning.

Thanks for your help.

By the way, do all power supplies have output capacitance? Is that just because of the capacitance of some components or is there some deeper meaning?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42234/discussion-between-user2943160-and-superciocia).

Comment: Also, please be aware that your coil is almost a short and the voltage across it will be low. Good constant current power supplies can regulate down to zero volt but not all. If you encounter problems, try adding a ~500 mohm resistor in series.